# Can too many API be bad?

Tags: performance, architecture, scalability

We have 3 applications, all the three are different technologies, Python, PHP and ASP.net.
These applications interact with each other using web-services. We have also used Docker for Continuous Integration. Again all these app are on different vm's, python is on Linux and other two are on windows. I have few questions:

1. Will there be any issue while scalability?
2. There are a lot of API calls across all the 3 apps will that hamper the app performance?

Comment: Bug fixing is a bit complicated sometimes probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, your application consists of a number of microservices written in various languages (which implies the use of microservices architecture). Now, here are the answers to your questions:

1. There shouldn't be any issue in scaling-out the services since that's one of the prime benefits of microservices architecture. In fact, you have the freedom of scaling-out each service individually.
2. Well, there certainly will be some network overhead, which is the case in most applications that use microservices. The use of a high bandwidth internal network for the purpose will make sure the calls over network do not hamper the performance (more details here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275734/how-do-microservice-system-architectures-avoid-network-bottlenecks).